# ASP.NET Core Integration Test UseLazyLoadingProxies requires AddEntityFrameworkProxies to be called on the internal service provider used

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I'm building a web service and I am trying to implement some integration tests, but when running the tests I'm seeing the following error;

```
UseLazyLoadingProxies requires AddEntityFrameworkProxies to be called on the internal service provider used.
```

Google does not bring up any useful results for this error and I do not know how to resolve it. I have tried adding `services.AddEntityFrameworkProxies()` to both my `Startup.cs` file, and the `CustomWebApplicationFactory.cs` file in my testing project. Neither have resolve the issue.

Here is my `CustomWebApplicationaFactory.cs` file from the IntegrationTests project;

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {   
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // Create a new service provider.
                var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();

                // Add a database context (AppDbContext) using an in-memory database for testing.
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryAppDb");
                    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
                });

                // Add a database context (AppDbContext) using an in-memory database for testing.
                services.AddDbContext<MultiTenantDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("MultiTenantInMemoryAppDb");
                    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
                });

                // Build the service provider.
                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                // Create a scope to obtain a reference to the database contexts
                using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                    var appDb = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

                    var logger = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>>>();

                    // Ensure the database is created.
                    appDb.Database.EnsureCreated();

                    try
                    {
                        // Seed the database with some specific test data.
                        SeedData.PopulateTestData(appDb);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the " +
                                            "database with test messages. Error: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by doing as the error was telling me. I added `AddEntityFrameworkProxies()` to the service provider;

```
// Create a new service provider.
                var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkProxies()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();
```